# Tracked files marked as untracked

Tags: git, merge

I have a local working copy on which I work, and a production working copy that I mostly only update (git pull).

For some reason, on that production working copy, I have 100 **"untracked files"** that should actually be tracked : they are files that I have already committed several times. As if I had copied them manually (but I didn't).

The consequence is, I can't pull because those 100 files can't merge...

Does anyone have a solution, and/or an explanation for this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

There was a revision where those files were part of your repository. You have told us so.

Then you switched your HEAD to a different revision, where those files were *not* part of your repository. But you left the files in your working copy (either by manually putting them back, or by using a `git reset` command in one of its forms).

So now the files are not tracked by the current checkout, but still live in your working copy.

The safest thing to do is to check the files in (make a new commit) and then merge with your upstream branch. `git pull` **could be** a merge, or it could be a rebase: which one it is depends on your git settings. So I recommend doing a `git fetch` and then a separate `git merge` to force a merge this once regardless of your general preferences.

When you see the merge conflicts, you should be able to get a better idea of what happened.

Comment: Thanks, but "git pull --merge" seems not to exist!

Comment: @theredled Try doing a `git fetch` and then a `git merge origin/<upstreambranchname>`.

Comment: I'm obtaining the same as with `git pull` : "Untracked working tree file 'shop/modules/aafront/controllers/front/subscriptionsList.php' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting"

Comment: @theredled I said you need to check the files in. This consists of running `git add` on them, and then doing a `git commit`. If the files are untracked, you have not checked them in.

Comment: Okay, it's getting better with `git add -A`. I thought `git commit -a` did the same. Now I have 100 conflicts... I never switched to a different revision, I don't understand why it's happening...

Comment: `git commit -a` will only commit changes in files which are tracked. Newly created files are not tracked. You should take a look at your conflicts and see what is different about these files. I suspect it will be illuminating.

Comment: Well, there's like they was before my last modifications... Nothing surprising...

Comment: Too complex stuff, I'll make a new clone.